# Awk Script to Check Every Line in a File

Tags: text-processing, awk, files

I'm having some trouble trying to create an awk script that checks and possibly corrects every line in a text file.

Consider the example:

```
$ cat employee.txt
"100","Thomas","Sales","5000"
"200","Jason","Technology","5500"
"300","Mayla",
"Technology","7000"
"400","Nisha","Marketing","9500"
"500","Randy","Techno
logy","6000"
"501","Ritu","Accounting","5400"
```

As you can see, some of the lines appear to be broken at the wrong point. The pattern should follow as such:

```
$ cat employee.txt
"100","Thomas","Sales","5000"
"200","Jason","Technology","5500"
"300","Mayla","Technology","7000"
"400","Nisha","Marketing","9500"
"500","Randy","Technology","6000"
"501","Ritu","Accounting","5400"
```

So I was wondering if there was a way in Awk to determine if the pattern isn't being followed, such as by verifying the number of commas in every line, and then backspacing the broken lines.

I receive files like this containing hundreds or thousands of rows, so manual work to fix all the broken lines is tedious.

I'm creating a control file to load data into a table using SQLLDR, but I get errors because the text file contains broken lines. So my solution is to fix every line by script.

Any thoughts? Script doesn't have to be in Awk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR == 1 { nf = NF } { while (NF < nf || !/[^,]"$/) { line = $0; getline; $0 = line $0 }; print }' file
"100","Thomas","Sales","5000"
"200","Jason","Technology","5500"
"300","Mayla","Technology","7000"
"400","Nisha","Marketing","9500"
"500","Randy","Technology","6000"
"501","Ritu","Accounting","5400"
```

This uses `awk` and *assumes that the 1st line has the correct number of fields* and that no field may contain embedded commas. It further assumes that no line will ever have *too many* fields, i.e. that a line may have extra newlines, but that no line is joined up with the next/previous line.

When a line with the wrong number of fields (or a line that does not end with a `"` character, which means that the last field was split) is found, the current line is saved in the variable `line` and the next line is read.  The current line is then updated as the concatenation of `line` and the line just read.  This continues (in the case of multiple consecutive split lines) until we end up with something that has the correct number of fields.  The reconstructed line is then printed.

`NF` is a special `awk` variable holding the number of fields in the current record (a record is a line by default). This number is updated automatically when `$0` (the current record) is assigned to or when a new record is read.  The `nf` variable is our own variable that is set to the "correct number of fields" from the first line.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Your code works, but if I wanted to skip the first line in the text file, wouldn't it be `FNR>1 { }` ? Because that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Phillip To discard the first line, do `'FNR == 1 { next } FNR == 2 { nf = NF } { ... }'`. That would not use the first line for anything.  Or just pass it through `sed 1d` first.

Comment: Thank you again, I wish I could give more appraisal to you. Is it possible to still print the first line rather than discarding it?

Comment: @Phillip Sure, insert `print;` just before `next` in the code in my previous comment. Next time, be sure to show the actual data that you are working with :-)

Comment: The actual data is very very large, so I just made a quick example and forgot the header of the txt file. Everything is perfect now, thanks to you.

Comment: @Phillip No worries, we sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply correct the text via regex:

```
<input.csv perl -pe 's/^(.+)([^"])\n$/\1\2/g'
```

gives you

```
"100","Thomas","Sales","5000"
"200","Jason","Technology","5500"
"300","Mayla","Technology","7000"
"400","Nisha","Marketing","9500"
"500","Randy","Technology","6000"
"501","Ritu","Accounting","5400"
```

Comment: This appears to fail if a line is split just in front of a comma.

Comment: @Kusalananda please share or edit your example input txt. Thank you

Comment: Break the `300` line into the two lines `"300","Mayla"` and `,"Technology","7000"`.  (this also breaks [RomanPerekhrest answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/148009/romanperekhrest) as it is currently written)

Comment: @Kusalananda it's in this way and it works https://i.imgur.com/vdOFw05.png

Comment: Move the comma after `"Mayla"` down to before `"Technology"` (this is how I mentioned it).

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry, you are right

Comment: No worries, I also have an issue in my code that nobody has dared mention yet, but I'll point it out and try to correct it...

Comment: You won. It's a great awk reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Short awk approach:

```
awk -F, '{ printf "%s%s", $0, $NF ~ /^$|[^"]$/? "":ORS }' file
```

- `$NF ~ /^$|[^"]$/` - check if last field `$NF` is either empty string `^$` OR a word without ending double quote `[^"]$`

The output:

```
"100","Thomas","Sales","5000"
"200","Jason","Technology","5500"
"300","Mayla","Technology","7000"
"400","Nisha","Marketing","9500"
"500","Randy","Technology","6000"
"501","Ritu","Accounting","5400"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, 'NF==4 { print $0 }; NF!=4 { str= $0; getline; print str $0 }' employee.txt

"100","Thomas","Sales","5000"
"200","Jason","Technology","5500"
"300","Mayla","Technology","7000"
"400","Nisha","Marketing","9500"
"500","Randy","Technology","6000"
"501","Ritu","Accounting","5400"
```